# How to get all rows from database by a foreign key value with Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I use Laravel on my website and Eloquent to manage my database. I have users with roles. This looks like this in my database :

```
|USERS                             |
|----------------------------------|
| ID | EMAIL | ... | ROLE_ID | ... |

|ROLES       |
|------------|
| ID | LABEL |
```

I would like to select user by their role label.

I tried to use joins and where functions but I don't know why the returned users have their `ID` set with their `ROLE_ID`.

```
    $admins = DB::table('users')
        ->leftJoin('roles', 'users.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
        ->where('roles.label','=', 'admin')
        ->get();
```

Here is one of the user returned :

```
object(stdClass)[285]
  public 'id' => int 3
  ...
  public 'role_id' => int 3
  ...
```

The `ID` of this user is 2 in the database. If I change it's `ROLE_ID` to 1, it's `ID` also change to 1.

I looked for solutions on the internet but I don't really know what to look for so I did not find anything.

I am sure this is quite simple but I am stuck anyway.

Comment: Most likely laravel doesn't know what Id to select since there's two IDs in the resultant result, try specifying what to pick with a `select()` https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#joins

Comment: Perfect, thanks ! That was indeed very simple...

Comment: Glad it worked out for you